# How to use aggregated result in order by clause with math operation in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query as below

```
select "products".*,
       AVG(score_values.score) as average_scores,
       (select count(*) from "comments" where "products"."id" = "comments"."product_id") as comments_count
from "products"
       inner join "score_values" on "products"."id" = "score_values"."product_id" and "score_values"."active" = 1
group by "products"."id"
order by average_scores desc
limit 5
```

When I add math operator to order clause, I get error which is column not exists.

```
order by average_scores * 0.9 + comments_count * 5 / 1000 desc
```

[42703] ERROR: column "average_scores" does not exist

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work around this by wrapping your query as a subquery, and the order in the outer query, like:

```
select *
from (
    select "products".*,
           AVG(score_values.score) as average_scores,
           (select count(*) from "comments" where "products"."id" = "comments"."product_id") as comments_count
    from "products"
           inner join "score_values" on "products"."id" = "score_values"."product_id" and "score_values"."active" = 1
    group by "products"."id"
    limit 5
) x
order by average_scores * 0.9 + comments_count * 5 / 1000 desc
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. Repeat the expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause:

   ```
   ORDER BY AVG(score_values.score) * 0.9
            + (select count(*) from "comments"
               where "products"."id" = "comments"."product_id") * 5 / 1000
   ```
2. Use a subquery like GMB's answer suggests.

The second option is the better one.

Note that this behavior [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-order.html):

> A ***sort_expression*** can also be the column label or number of an output column, as in:
>
> ```
> SELECT a + b AS sum, c FROM table1 ORDER BY sum;
> SELECT a, max(b) FROM table1 GROUP BY a ORDER BY 1;
> ```
>
> both of which sort by the first output column. Note that an output column name has to stand alone, that is, it cannot be used in an expression — for example, this is not correct:
>
> ```
> SELECT a + b AS sum, c FROM table1 ORDER BY sum + c;          -- wrong
> ```
>
> This restriction is made to reduce ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregate expressions in the `order by` clause. The aggregates will be calculated once.

```
select 
    products.*,
    avg(score_values.score) as average_scores,
    count(comments.*) as comments_count
from products
inner join comments on products.id = comments.product_id
inner join score_values on products.id = score_values.product_id and score_values.active = 1
group by products.id
order by avg(score_values.score) * 0.9 + count(comments.*) * 5 / 1000 desc
limit 5
```

Comment: That's really interesting. I didn't know Postgres is smart enough for duplicated statements

Comment: is there a documentation about it ?

Comment: Well, probably, but I don't remember where. You can easily check this in a query plan (using `explain <query>`).